# the sign of a function of two variable

Tags: multivariable-calculus

let $f$ a functions of two variables such that

$$f(x,m)=16+\frac{x^2 \Bigg(8(m+3)(m+2)(m+1)-4 (m+2)x^2\Bigg)}{16(m+4)(m+3)(m+2)(m+1)-4 (m+2)(3m+9)x^2+x^{4}} -\frac{x^2\Bigg(8(m-3)(m-2)(m-1)-4 (m-2)x^2\Bigg)}{16(m-4)(m-3)(m-2)(m-1)-4x^2 (m-2)(3m-9)+x^{4}}$$
I want to prove that 
$f(x,m)\leq 0 $ for $m\geq 9$ and $x\in [2\sqrt{(m-1)(m-2)},2\sqrt{(m+1)(m+2)}]$
thanks for any suggestion

Comment: Have you tried plotting it for a few values of $m$ to make sure the result is true? This could also yield insight on how to proceed.

Comment: yes, I have plot the curve for few values of m ,the result is true 
but how to prove it ? the hessian is quite lenght ....., 
I am working on an idea , thank you for the suggestion zach

Comment: Great. If you happen to have a typical plot to include in the question, maybe that will generate some ideas...